# Checking if the username already exists in google's datastore using Java

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

EDIT: Alex Martelli Gave me a great answer which I changed only slightly in order to get working properly for me

The answer to this problem for me was

```
public boolean Login2(String usernamein, String passwordin) {
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory
            .getDatastoreService();

    Filter usernamefilter = new FilterPredicate("username",
            FilterOperator.EQUAL, usernamein);

    Query validuserquery = new Query("Users").setFilter(usernamefilter)
            .setKeysOnly();

    Entity theUser = datastore.prepare(validuserquery).asSingleEntity();

    if (theUser == null) {
        System.out.println("Username not found");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

End of EDIT

Original Post
Okay so I have spent the entire day trying to do this and have tried my best to research it but I can't do it! :(

I feel like there is probably and easy answer but I can't work it out, I feel like I have tried Everything! please please please help D:

I have a Login section of code on its own .jsp page called Index.jsp

```
String username = "";
    String password = "";

    try {
        if (request.getParameter("usernamein") != null && request.getParameter("passwordin") != null) {
            username = (request.getParameter("usernamein"));
            password = request.getParameter("passwordin");
            if(login.Login2(username, password)){
                response.sendRedirect("Race.jsp");
                System.out.println("go to next page");
            } else {//need username/password
                out.println("your username or password is incorrect");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println("problem in getting u an p error =" + e);
    }
```

Part way through that code is the line (login.Login2(username, password))
that code calls a method in a class using java use bean thingy
the method it calls is this:

```
public boolean Login2(String usernamein, String passwordin) {
        DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        Filter usernamefilter = new FilterPredicate("username", FilterOperator.EQUAL, usernamein);

        Query validuserquery = new Query("Users");
        validuserquery.addProjection(new PropertyProjection("username", null));
        System.out.println(validuserquery);

        List<Entity> list = datastore.prepare(validuserquery).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(100));
        System.out.println(list);

        for (Entity username : list){
            System.out.println("username is equal to '"+username+"'");
            if(username.equals(usernamein)){
                return true;
            }else
                System.out.println("was not equal");
                return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I'm trying to only go to the next page in the top code if the if statement is true, meaning that the username does exist, eventually I want it to only go to then next page if the username and password are both in the same entity i.e. the combination exists.

I hope you guys understand what i am trying to do and can help me

oh the System.out.println() for the username value outputs this:

```
username is equal to '<Entity [user("id")/Users(5910974510923776)]:
    username = RawValue [value=[B@187c4d7]
>
'
```

If you need any more info just ask and i'll add it to the post :D ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be best advised to query the datastore for just the username of interest...:

```
Query validuserquery = new Query("Users").
    setFilter(new Query.FilterPredicate("username", 
                  Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL,
                  usernamein)
    ).setKeysOnly();
Entity anyentity = datastore.prepare(validuserquery).asSingleEntity();
if(anyentity == null) {
    System.out.println("was not equal");
    return false;
}
return true;
```

This assumes there are no entities with duplicated `username` in your store (though you could deal with that by catching exception `PreparedQuery.TooManyResultsException` -- if **that** gets raised, it means you have more than one entity with that username, so that would be a `return true` case too:-).

The core idea is: getting every user entity and checking their usernames in your application code is really wasteful of resources (quite apart from the bugs in your code in this case) -- use **queries** to get only the **relevant** entity or entities, if any!-)

Comment: `Entity anyentity = datastore.prepare(validuserquery).asSingleEntity()` needs a **;** at the end  
`Query.FilterPredicate` also gives me an error  
"The method FilterPredicate(String, Query.FilterOperator, String) is undefined for the type Query"

Comment: @LiamMurray60 `Query.FilterPredicate` is not a method, it's a class, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Query.FilterPredicate.  Editing to fix the typo about missing a `;`...

Answer (score -1):

Try searching a bit more next time. It's not that hard, your issue was pretty easy. In any case :

Your query returns a full object, not just properties of your object. You need to do

```
entity.getProperty("username")
```

So that you see your property, not the full object.

More info [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries).